# Distinct Count with data from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 4 tables[image: tables]

All ID related things are ints and the rest are texts.
I want to count the number of albums the user is tagged at so if a user is tagged in album1 once album2 once and album3 once it will show 3 and if more in any of them it will still show 3.
I tried to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ALBUM_ID) FROM PICTURES WHERE ID=(SELECT PICTURE_ID FROM TAGS WHERE USER_ID=userId);
```

But this returned 1 although it was supposed to return 3 and the same happened without `DISTINCT`.
How can I get the amount?
**EDIT:**
I want to check only one user(I have the user's ID and name)

Comment: Hard to help much without sample data. But what is your sub-query returning?

Comment: It returns different values that represent ID's of pictures that the user Is tagged at(3 values here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must join `users` with `LEFT` joins to `tags` and `pictures` and aggregate:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(DISTINCT p.album_id) counter
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN pictures p ON p.id = t.picture_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
```

If you want the result for a specific user only:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, COUNT(DISTINCT p.album_id) counter
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN pictures p ON p.id = t.picture_id
WHERE u.id = ?
GROUP BY u.id, u.name -- you may omit this line, because SQLite allows it
```

Or with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, 
       (
         SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.album_id)
         FROM tags t INNER JOIN pictures p 
         ON p.id = t.picture_id
         WHERE t.user_id = u.id 
       ) counter
FROM users u
WHERE u.id = ?
```

Replace `?` with the id of the user that you want.

Comment: And put the details of the user that I want to check at the end?

Comment: @Velanar32 do you mean that you want the query for a specific userid only?

Comment: @Velanar32 see my edited answer with a WHERE clause.